# Cube Calculation median age (MDX)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to create cube calculation for median Age in a HR cube.

Measures: head count and FTE

Dimension:  Age (Age, Age_Group, ...), Duty_type, Staff (Staff_ID, ...), Date, etc

I tried to use the following MDX script:

```
Median([Month Date].[Staff Profile Month Date - Hierarchy].[Month Date Calendar Year].currentmember.Children ,IIF([Age].[Age].currentmember.name ='All' ,0,StrToValue([Age].[Age].currentmember.name)))
```

I used the following help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145570.aspx

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Create base measure called Sum Age(make it invisible) and use this to create median calculated measure.

```
Median([Staff].[Staff ID].currentmember.children,[Measures].[Sum Age])
```